# Convert comma seperated string to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I convert this string to array with `lenght=4` and all items being strings?

```
var str= "[bc, cccc, 14.35],[B, 222],[222, p11, 11s],[cccc, 14.35, D, 11s]";
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the first and the last brackets and use `split` function.
Here is the working code snippet which converts your string to 4 strings without any brackets or outer commas.

```js
var s = "[bc, cccc, 14.35],[B, 222],[222, p11, 11s],[cccc, 14.35, D, 11s]";

var sArr = s.substr(1, s.length - 2).split('],[');

for (var k in sArr)
    document.body.innerHTML += sArr[k] + "<br/><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript [split("spacer")](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to perform this task :

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var str = "[bc, cccc, 14.35],[B, 222],[222, p11, 11s],[cccc, 14.35, D, 11s]";
var str_array = str.split("],");
console.log(str_array.lenght); // display "4"
```

I used `],` as spacer because you would have some others elements to be splitted as they contain several commas.

**SPECIFIC ADVICE**
If you need to remove `]` and `[` remaining characters, you can use [replace("to_be_replaced", "replacer")](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) as followed :

```
str_array.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.replace("]", "");
    entry.replace("[", "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str= "[bc, cccc, 14.35],[B, 222],[222, p11, 11s],[cccc, 14.35, D, 11s]".split("],[");
```

Comment: Hi, please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Following will preserve `]` if you want that:

```
var str= "[bc, cccc, 14.35],[B, 222],[222, p11, 11s],[cccc, 14.35, D, 11s]";
var res = str.split('],').join(']],').split('],')
```

Result:

```
res = ["[bc, cccc, 14.35]","[B, 222]","[222, p11, 11s]","[cccc, 14.35, D, 11s]"]
```

```js
 var str = "[bc, cccc, 14.35],[B, 222],[222, p11, 11s],[cccc, 14.35, D, 11s]";
 var res = str.split('],').join(']],').split('],')
 for (var k in res) {
   document.body.innerHTML += res[k] + "<br/>"
 }
```